# How to fix the size of vectors on surfaces so they are in correct proportion?

Tags: plotting

I'm having a hard time understanding how vector sizes work with the SliceVectorPlot3D[] function.  In my code below, I used a basic inverse square vector field, expecting vectors of the same length on the outer sphere.

```
SliceVectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}/Norm[{x, y, z}]^3, {x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 25,
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 4}, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, {z, -6, 6}, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], VectorPoints -> 7, 
 VectorColorFunction -> LightBlue, VectorColorFunctionScaling -> None,
  Ticks -> None, Axes -> False, VectorScale -> 0.04, 
 VectorScaling -> "Sqrt", VectorMarkers -> Placed["Arrow3D", "Start"]]
```

However, for some reason, the vectors on the outer sphere have various sizes, as shown in the figure below.  Perhaps the inner sphere has the same problem, but I can't tell.
[image]

It tried fixing them by messing with the vector scaling option but that didn't work.  I could choose "none" for vector scaling which makes all vectors have the same length but then the vectors on the inner sphere would be the same size as the vectors on the outer sphere which I do not want. In general, for any plot, I would like all vectors to be in the correct proportion.

For this particular case, the vectors on the inner sphere should be larger since the field is stronger there, but all vectors on either sphere should have the same lengths.

Any ideas on why I'm getting varying sizes and how to fix it?

Comment: I believe the first problem (a bug?) lies in using `VectorScaling -> "Sqrt"` – try removing that. The second thing is that it looks like the vector scaling is done separately for each surface, therefore, you should use `Show[SliceVectorPlot3D[..., surf1], SliceVectorPlot3D[..., surf2]]`.

Comment: @Domen Thank you.  This works.  Yes, it seems vector scaling is not working right.  But splitting it up into plots worked like a charm.

Comment: I think you should report the bug in `VectorScaling` to the technical support.